# Convert custom strings to datetime format

Tags: python, date, converters

I have a list of date-time data strings that looks like this:

```
list = ["2016-08-02T09:20:32.456Z", "2016-07-03T09:22:35.129Z"]
```

I want to convert this to the example format (for the first item):

```
"8/2/2016 9:20:32 AM"
```

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
for time in list:
    date = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y %m %d %I %R')
```

But returns error:

> ValueError: 'R' is a bad directive in format '%Y %m %d %I %R'

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The date format that you are using does not match the items of your list. And what is `%R` supposed to mean?

Comment: It's supposed to mean the time in 24hour duration: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm

Comment: Strange, it does not appear in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#id1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems in you code:

- `%R`doesn't seem to be a [correct directive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) (that's your error, I think you are looking for `%p`).
- the format in strptime is the format of your input, not the output
- you are using `list` and `time` as a name variable which is bad ;]

So, you could for first convert you time to a correct datetime object:

```
>>> t='2016-08-02T09:20:32.456Z'
>>> d=datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 9, 20, 32, 456000)
```

And then convert this object to a string with strftime

```
>>> datetime.strftime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
'08/02/2016 09:20:32 AM'
```

Comment: Thanks for the better answer and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "2016-08-02T09:20:32.456Z"
d = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

The use `d.strftime` (https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#id1).