# Comparing two dates in different formats

Tags: python, datetime, format

I have two dates, one is a string in following format,

```
"2022-07-03T12:23:49.000Z"
```

The other is a `datetime` object from this:

```
minimumDate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=10)
```

How can I format them so I can compare them both?

P.S. I am not familiar with python, just  use it for a project.

Comment: You'll want to compare datetime objects. So you'll have to convert the ISO format string to that, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your format of date to datetime object using the below:

```
date_str = "2022-07-03T12:23:49.000Z"
date_formatted = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Then both the formatted date(date_formatted) and minimumDate will be in datetime format to compare, as shown below.

```
minimumDate - date_formatted
```

Below is the reference for the answer: [Convert custom strings to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041398/convert-custom-strings-to-datetime-format)

Comment: You probably don't want to ignore the Z - that's UTC while datetime.today returns naive datetime, thus *local* time.

Comment: Since `date_formatted` and `minimumDate` are both `datetime` objects they can be compared directly — i.e. `if date_formatted > minimumDate:`. I also suggest using the third-party `dateutil` module which will parse the timezone properly. It's easy to install from the command line via: `pip install python-dateutil`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable minimumDate is type 'datetime.datetime' to compare both you need to convert it in a string

```
minimumDate = str(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=10))
```

That way both are strings

Comment: If I converted  to string how can I compare it as a date I need to know if date is greater then another date